# Почему при команде sudo service apache2 start ничего не происходит?

Tags: ubuntu, apache, apache2, wsl, wsl2

Решил переустановить apache2 на WSL Ubuntu 20.04, зачистил его полностью, установил по инструкции.

Пытаюсь теперь включить sudo service apache2 start, ничего не происходит, консоль команду просто игнорирует:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

error.log пустой

если попробовать запустить другой сервер sudo service nginx start, то все работает, я его включил и отключил, sudo service postgresql start тоже работает...

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина?

Команда sudo service status приводит к такому же результату, как и sudo service apache2 start, она просто пропускается, не выводится никакого текста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего сервис Apache2 не активирован в systemd
Для проверки посмотрите присутствует ли файл /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/@apache2.service

Для активации сервиса

```
sudo systemctl enable apache2.service
```

После этого у Вас должны начать работать команды

sudo service apache2 start/stop/status

Answer (score 1):

Написать

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

Возможно, что-то станет понятнее.

Comment: то же самое... команда просто пропускается без какого либо текста.